# PowerShell: greater than comparison not working in hashtable

Tags: powershell, foreach, comparison, hashtable

I have the following data, and I'm trying to use this foreach loop to iterate through it and return each row where the value is greater than a specific number.

```
$tables
ABC_USER_ACTIVITY_LOG          1.05                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
HH_MESSAGE_LOG                 3.57                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ABC_SDM_GCC_HIST               6.58                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
QQ_ORDER_HISTORY               1.07                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
FG_USER                        9.72                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
AC_MESSAGE_LOG_DETAIL          4.10                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
DS_DATA_MESSAGE_LOG            0.85                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
AS_SECURITY                    31.76                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
AS_ORDER_PLACEMENT             2.27                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
AS_ORDER                       6.99
```

```
$maxsize = 4
foreach ($Key in ($tables.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value -gt $maxsize})) {

    Write-Host $key.name "=" $key.Value

}
```

Since $maxsize = 4 I would expect there to be 5 rows returned, but it only returns the following:

```
ABC_SDM_GCC_HIST = 6.58
FG_USER = 9.72
AC_MESSAGE_LOG_DETAIL = 4.10
AS_ORDER = 6.99
```

How can I make sure the -gt comparison is working correctly and pulls back all the required values? Does it not recognize double-digit numbers and only looks at the first number in the value, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I ran your code and it returned 5 rows: `AS_ORDER = 6.99
FG_USER = 9.72
ABC_SDM_GCC_HIST = 6.58
AC_MESSAGE_LOG_DETAIL = 4.1
AS_SECURITY = 31.76`

Comment: Can you copy, and paste it in a new runspace/powershell tab (if in ise)?

Comment: The most likely problem here is that the values in the hashtable are _strings_, not numbers, so PowerShell converts `$maxSize` to a string - and `"31.76"` happens to be _alphabetically_ lower ranking than `"4"` - change `$_.Value -gt $maxsize` -> `$maxsize -lt $_.Value` and it will work

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you, that worked!